# JavaScript sum multidimensional array element values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array and I need to calculate the sum of the values per group. I can get the sum for each group for the first value at dataArr[1] of the array, but I need to also get the sum for the second value at dataArr[2] for each group in the array.

```
var dataArr = [    [
    "Group One",
    1,
    1
],
[
    "Group Four",
    0,
    1
],
[
    "Group Three",
    0,
    1
],
[
    "Group Three",
    1,
    0
],
[
    "Group Four",
    0,
    1
],
[
    "Group Two",
    2,
    1
],
[
    "Group Four",
    1,
    0
],
[
    "Group Three",
    0,
    1
],
[
    "Group Three",
    0,
    1
],
[
    "Group One",
    1,
    0
],
[
    "Group Three",
    0,
    1
],
[
    "Group Two",
    1,
    0
]
];
```

How to calculate the sum of the second value and generate a multidimensional array like the following:

`[["Group One", 2, 1], ["Group Four", 1, 2], ["Group Three", 1, 4], ["Group Two", 3, 1]]`

Below is my code inspired from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608338/summing-totals-in-javascript-array):

```
var result = [];

$(dataArr).each(function() {
    var key = this[0];
    var value = this[1];

    if (result[key]) {
        result[key] += value;       
    } else {
        result[key] = value;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This proposal uses a temporary object for the reference to the result array.

```js
var dataArr = [["Group One", 1, 1], ["Group Four", 0, 1], ["Group Three", 0, 1], ["Group Three", 1, 0], ["Group Four", 0, 1], ["Group Two", 2, 1], ["Group Four", 1, 0], ["Group Three", 0, 1], ["Group Three", 0, 1], ["Group One", 1, 0], ["Group Three", 0, 1], ["Group Two", 1, 0]],
    result = function (data) {
        var r = [], o = {};
        data.forEach(function (a) {
            if (!o[a[0]]) {
                o[a[0]] = [a[0], 0, 0];
                r.push(o[a[0]]);
            }
            o[a[0]][1] += a[1];
            o[a[0]][2] += a[2];
        });
        return r;
    }(dataArr);
    
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with `Array.forEach`, `Object.keys` and `Array.map` methods:

```
var keys_obj = {}, key;
dataArr.forEach(function(v){
    key = v[0];
    if (! (key in keys_obj) ) {
        keys_obj[key] = [v[1], v[2]];
    } else {
        keys_obj[key][0] += v[1];
        keys_obj[key][1] += v[2];
    }
});

var result = [];
result = Object.keys(keys_obj).map(function(v){
    return [v, keys_obj[v][0], keys_obj[v][1]];
});

console.log(result);

// the output: 
[["Group Four", 1, 2], ["Group Three", 1, 4], ["Group One", 2, 1], ["Group Two", 3, 1]]
```

Comment: To reduce some of the bracket madness, I'd personally suggest keeping the `key` variable.

Comment: @Phrogz, added `key` variable for convenience

Answer (score 0):

1. Use an object instead of an array to track custom properties.
2. Instead of a single value per key, use an array per key. Now you can support, 1, 2, or 47 values per object.
3. In case you have more than 2 values in the future, I suggest using a `for` loop to generically handle them all.

```js
var dataArr = [["Group One",1,1],["Group Four",0,1],["Group Three",0,1],
               ["Group Three",1,0],["Group Four",0,1],["Group Two",2,1],
               ["Group Four",1,0],["Group Three",0,1],["Group Three",0,1],
               ["Group One",1,0],["Group Three",0,1],["Group Two",1,0]];

var sumByKey = {};
dataArr.forEach(function(item){
  var key = item[0];
  if (!sumByKey[key]) sumByKey[key] = [];
  for (var i=0;i<2;++i){
    sumByKey[key][i] = (sumByKey[key][i] || 0) + item[i+1];
  }
});

var output = neatJSON(sumByKey,{wrap:30,short:true,aligned:true});
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<script src="http://phrogz.net/JS/neatjson/neatjson.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

With [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) methods:

```
var reduced = dataArr.reduce(function(obj,item) {
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(item[0])) {
    obj[item[0]][0] += item[1]
    obj[item[0]][1] += item[2]
  } else {
    obj[item[0]] = []
    obj[item[0]][0] = item[1]
    obj[item[0]][1] = item[2]
  }
  return obj;
}, {});
var grouped = Object.keys(reduced).map(function(item) {
  return [item, reduced [item][0], reduced [item][1]]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With object and [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method

```
var o = {};
dataArr.forEach(function(e) {
    var t = o[e[0]];
    if (t) {
        t.first += e[1];
        t.second += e[2];
    } else {
        t = {};
        t.first = e[1];
        t.second = e[2];
        o[e[0]] = t;
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
console.log(o["Group Four"].first); // first sum for "Group Four"
console.log(o["Group Four"].second); // second sum for "Group Four"

console.log(o); // all groups with their sums
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach to this old (and seemingly common) problem by using the `Map` object and the `reduce` and `map` functions.

```js
const dataArr = [
  ['Group One', 1, 1],
  ['Group Four', 0, 1],
  ['Group Three', 0, 1],
  ['Group Three', 1, 0],
  ['Group Four', 0, 1],
  ['Group Two', 2, 1],
  ['Group Four', 1, 0],
  ['Group Three', 0, 1],
  ['Group Three', 0, 1],
  ['Group One', 1, 0],
  ['Group Three', 0, 1],
  ['Group Two', 1, 0],
];

const sumArray = (data) =>
  Array.from(
    data.reduce((accum, item) => {
      let prev = accum.get(item[0]) || [0, 0];
      accum.set(item[0], [prev[0] + item[1], prev[1] + item[2]]);

      return accum;
    }, new Map())
  ).map((entry) => [entry[0], entry[1][0], entry[1][1]]);

console.log(sumArray(dataArr));
```

A `Map` instance is used as an accumulator in the `reduce`, and it stores "tuples" of the sums for each "Group", it is then converted to an array and mapped (no pun inteded) to flatten it into the same `[[string, number, number]]` shape as the original data.